# Using Parcelable on a Library Class

Tags: android, parcelable, parcel

I want to send an object between Activities. Reading up on this i have come to conclusion that using Parcelable is the best way to go as it has the least performance impacts. The reason i want to do this is because i need to download data from the network to create an Object, so i don't want to keep downloading the data.

However, in order to use a Parcel the class needs to implement Parcelable. As i am trying to send an Object defined in a Library i cannot edit the class to include this.

What would be the best way to solve my predicament?

I have tried extending the library class and implementing Parcelable but failed with a ClassCastException. I have also seen mentioned that i should make a Parcelable  class that wraps around my library class and send it that way?

Thanks!

Comment: Either way at some point you will need to extend your library class and implement serializable.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [parceler library](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler)? You can [tell your `Application` to parcel library classes](https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler#classes-without-java-source):

> ```
> @ParcelClass(LibraryParcel.class)
> public class AndroidApplication extends Application{
>     //...
> }
> ```

If that works, you could use the following code to wrap/unwrap:

> ```
> Parcelable wrapped = Parcels.wrap(new Example("Andy", 42));
> Example example = Parcels.unwrap(wrapped);
> example.getName(); // Andy
> example.getAge(); // 42
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to use [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) ?

For example if you have parcelable class User

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
String userName = user.setUserName("some name");
boolean isOnline = user.setOnline(true);
users.add(user);
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("USER", users);
```

And you may retrieve this as:

```
public ArrayList<User> getParcelableArrayList(Bundle bundle){
   List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();
   userList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("USER");
}
```